# Google OAuth2 authentication issue: no web browser response after user consent

Tags: python, authentication, oauth-2.0, google-authentication, oauth2client

## Issue

Making an standalone (non-web) app which utilizes Google Drive API for multi-platform data synchronization. During OAuth2 authentication (oauth2client.tools.run_flow), web browser does not respond (= issue) sometimes after user's consent. (When such issue happens, by refreshing the web page, the authorization is returned with no problem, but I think the user might just feel it is frozen.)
This happens for Mac OS Catalina, Windows 10 and iOS 14.
Using Python 3.7.6 + Kivy.

## Details

I can reproduce my issue even with the standard sample code (The code used here is just a slight modification of Google Drive example on Github, from https://github.com/dtsvetkov1/Google-Drive-sync).
In the code,

```
credentials = tools.run_flow(flow, store, flags=None)
```

opens user consent screen on the web browser like this pic
[(press here for the image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Bucw.png)
Pressing "Allow" button, the browser returns redirect to localhost and the app finishes the oauth2 authentication in the case of normal operation. However, sometimes the browser keep waiting, time outs and authentication fails. Before time out, if I refresh the web page, the browser returns redirect to localhost, just like no issue has happened.

I followed the instruction (https://medium.com/swlh/google-drive-api-with-python-part-i-set-up-credentials-1f729cb0372b) to enable Google Drive API, set up OAuth2 client ID, created client_secret.json on the Google developer console and stored the json file in the current folder.

I also tried

```
 flow = OAuth2WebServerFlow(client_id=App.s.ClientID,
                                       client_secret=ClientSecret,
                                       scope=SCOPES,
                                       redirect_uri="urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob:auto" 
                                       )
```

but the same result.
Any idea how to solve this problem?

## Sample code

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

"""Example cooment to make pylint stop giving me errors."""

import datetime
import hashlib
import mimetypes
import time
import os
import httplib2

from apiclient import discovery
from oauth2client import client
from oauth2client import tools
# from oauth2client.tools import run

from oauth2client.file import Storage
from apiclient.http import MediaFileUpload
# Import our folder uploading script
# import initial_upload

# If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
# at ~/.credentials/drive-python-quickstart.json
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly',
          'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file',
          'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = 'client_secret.json'
APPLICATION_NAME = 'Drive Sync'

# Declare full path to folder and folder name
# FULL_PATH = r'PUT YOUR FULL FOLDER PATH HERE'
FULL_PATH = APPPATH = os.path.normpath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), '..'))
DIR_NAME = 'testgdrive'
# Or simply
# DIR_NAME = FULL_PATH.split('/')[-1]

# Don't really need it here
GOOGLE_MIME_TYPES = {
    'application/vnd.google-apps.document':
    'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document',
    # 'application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text',
    'application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet':
    'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet',
    # 'application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet',
    'application/vnd.google-apps.presentation':
    'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation'
    # 'application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation'
}

# 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder': '',
# 'application/vnd.google-apps.form': 'application/pdf',
# 'application/vnd.google-apps.fusiontable': '',
# 'application/vnd.google-apps.map': 'application/pdf',
# 'application/vnd.google-apps.photo': 'image/jpeg',
# 'application/vnd.google-apps.file': '',
# 'application/vnd.google-apps.sites': '',
# 'application/vnd.google-apps.unknown': '',
# 'application/vnd.google-apps.video': '',
# 'application/vnd.google-apps.audio': '',
# 'application/vnd.google-apps.drive-sdk': ''
# 'application/octet-stream': 'text/plain'


def folder_upload(service):
    '''Uploads folder and all it's content (if it doesnt exists)
    in root folder.

    Args:
        items: List of folders in root path on Google Drive.
        service: Google Drive service instance.

    Returns:
        Dictionary, where keys are folder's names
        and values are id's of these folders.
    '''

    parents_id = {}

    for root, _, files in os.walk(FULL_PATH, topdown=True):
        last_dir = root.split('/')[-1]
        pre_last_dir = root.split('/')[-2]
        if pre_last_dir not in parents_id.keys():
            pre_last_dir = []
        else:
            pre_last_dir = parents_id[pre_last_dir]

        folder_metadata = {'name': last_dir,
                           'parents': [pre_last_dir],
                           'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'}
        create_folder = service.files().create(body=folder_metadata,
                                               fields='id').execute()
        folder_id = create_folder.get('id', [])

        for name in files:
            file_metadata = {'name': name, 'parents': [folder_id]}
            media = MediaFileUpload(
                os.path.join(root, name),
                mimetype=mimetypes.MimeTypes().guess_type(name)[0])
            service.files().create(body=file_metadata,
                                   media_body=media,
                                   fields='id').execute()

        parents_id[last_dir] = folder_id

    return parents_id


def check_upload(service):
    """Checks if folder is already uploaded,
    and if it's not, uploads it.

    Args:
        service: Google Drive service instance.

    Returns:
        ID of uploaded folder, full path to this folder on computer.

    """

    results = service.files().list(
        pageSize=100,
        q="'root' in parents and trashed != True and \
        mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder'").execute()

    items = results.get('files', [])

    # Check if folder exists, and then create it or get this folder's id.
    if DIR_NAME in [item['name'] for item in items]:
        folder_id = [item['id']for item in items
                     if item['name'] == DIR_NAME][0]
    else:
        parents_id = folder_upload(service)
        folder_id = parents_id[DIR_NAME]

    return folder_id, FULL_PATH


def get_credentials():
    """Gets valid user credentials from storage.

    If nothing has been stored, or if the stored credentials are invalid,
    the OAuth2 flow is completed to obtain the new credentials.

    Returns:
        Credentials, the obtained credential.
    """
    home_dir = os.path.expanduser('~')
    credential_dir = os.path.join(home_dir, '.credentials')
    if not os.path.exists(credential_dir):
        os.makedirs(credential_dir)
    credential_path = os.path.join(credential_dir,
                                   'drive-python-sync.json')

    store = Storage(credential_path)
    credentials = store.get()
    if not credentials or credentials.invalid:
        flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, SCOPES)
        flow.user_agent = APPLICATION_NAME
        # if flags:
        credentials = tools.run_flow(flow, store, flags=None)
        # else:  # Needed only for compatibility with Python 2.6
        # flags = None
        # credentials = tools.run_flow(flow, store, flags)
        print('Storing credentials to ', credential_path)
    return credentials


def get_tree(folder_name, tree_list, root, parents_id, service):
    """Gets folder tree relative paths.

    Recursively gets through subfolders, remembers their names ad ID's.

    Args:
        folder_name: Name of folder, initially
        name of parent folder string.
        folder_id: ID of folder, initially ID of parent folder.
        tree_list: List of relative folder paths, initially
        empy list.
        root: Current relative folder path, initially empty string.
        parents_id: Dictionary with pairs of {key:value} like
        {folder's name: folder's Drive ID}, initially empty dict.
        service: Google Drive service instance.

    Returns:
        List of folder tree relative folder paths.

    """
    folder_id = parents_id[folder_name]

    results = service.files().list(
        pageSize=1000,
        q=("%r in parents and \
        mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'and \
        trashed != True" % folder_id)).execute()

    items = results.get('files', [])
    root += folder_name + os.path.sep

    for item in items:
        parents_id[item['name']] = item['id']
        tree_list.append(root + item['name'])
        folder_id = [i['id'] for i in items
                     if i['name'] == item['name']][0]
        folder_name = item['name']
        get_tree(folder_name, tree_list,
                 root, parents_id, service)


def by_lines(input_str):
    """Helps Sort items by the number of slashes in it.

    Returns:
        Number of slashes in string.
    """
    return input_str.count(os.path.sep)


def main():
    """Syncronizes computer folder with Google Drive folder.

    Checks files if they exist, uploads new files and subfolders,
    deletes old files from Google Drive and refreshes existing stuff.
    """
    credentials = get_credentials()
    http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
    service = discovery.build('drive', 'v3', http=http)

    # Get id of Google Drive folder and it's path (from other script)
    # folder_id, full_path = initial_upload.check_upload(service)
    folder_id, full_path = check_upload(service)
    folder_name = full_path.split(os.path.sep)[-1]
    tree_list = []
    root = ''
    parents_id = {}

    parents_id[folder_name] = folder_id
    get_tree(folder_name, tree_list, root, parents_id, service)
    os_tree_list = []
    root_len = len(full_path.split(os.path.sep)[0:-2])

    # Get list of folders three paths on computer
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(full_path, topdown=True):
        for name in dirs:
            var_path = (os.path.sep).join(
                root.split(os.path.sep)[root_len + 1:])
            os_tree_list.append(os.path.join(var_path, name))

    # old folders on drive
    remove_folders = list(set(tree_list).difference(set(os_tree_list)))
    # new folders on drive, which you dont have(i suppose hehe)
    upload_folders = list(set(os_tree_list).difference(set(tree_list)))
    # foldes that match
    exact_folders = list(set(os_tree_list).intersection(set(tree_list)))

    # Add starting directory
    exact_folders.append(folder_name)
    # Sort uploadable folders
    # so now in can be upload from top to down of tree
    upload_folders = sorted(upload_folders, key=by_lines)

    # Here we upload new (abcent on Drive) folders
    for folder_dir in upload_folders:
        var = os.path.join(full_path.split(os.path.sep)[0:-1]) + os.path.sep
        variable = var + folder_dir
        last_dir = folder_dir.split(os.path.sep)[-1]
        pre_last_dir = folder_dir.split(os.path.sep)[-2]

        files = [f for f in os.listdir(variable)
                 if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(variable, f))]

        folder_metadata = {'name': last_dir,
                           'parents': [parents_id[pre_last_dir]],
                           'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'}
        create_folder = service.files().create(
            body=folder_metadata, fields='id').execute()
        folder_id = create_folder.get('id', [])
        parents_id[last_dir] = folder_id

        for os_file in files:
            some_metadata = {'name': os_file, 'parents': [folder_id]}
            os_file_mimetype = mimetypes.MimeTypes().guess_type(
                os.path.join(variable, os_file))[0]
            media = MediaFileUpload(os.path.join(variable, os_file),
                                    mimetype=os_file_mimetype)
            upload_this = service.files().create(body=some_metadata,
                                                 media_body=media,
                                                 fields='id').execute()
            upload_this = upload_this.get('id', [])

    # Check files in existed folders and replace them
    # with newer versions if needed
    for folder_dir in exact_folders:

        var = (os.path.sep).join(full_path.split(
            os.path.sep)[0:-1]) + os.path.sep

        variable = var + folder_dir
        last_dir = folder_dir.split(os.path.sep)[-1]
        # print(last_dir, folder_dir)
        os_files = [f for f in os.listdir(variable)
                    if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(variable, f))]
        results = service.files().list(
            pageSize=1000, q=('%r in parents and \
            mimeType!="application/vnd.google-apps.folder" and \
            trashed != True' % parents_id[last_dir]),
            fields="files(id, name, mimeType, \
            modifiedTime, md5Checksum)").execute()

        items = results.get('files', [])

        refresh_files = [f for f in items if f['name'] in os_files]
        remove_files = [f for f in items if f['name'] not in os_files]
        upload_files = [f for f in os_files
                        if f not in [j['name']for j in items]]

        # Check files that exist both on Drive and on PC
        for drive_file in refresh_files:
            file_dir = os.path.join(variable, drive_file['name'])
            file_time = os.path.getmtime(file_dir)
            mtime = [f['modifiedTime']
                     for f in items if f['name'] == drive_file['name']][0]
            mtime = datetime.datetime.strptime(
                mtime[:-2], "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f")
            drive_time = time.mktime(mtime.timetuple())
            # print(drive_file['name'])
            # if file['mimeType'] in GOOGLE_MIME_TYPES.keys():
            # print(file['name'], file['mimeType'])
            # print()
            os_file_md5 = hashlib.md5(open(file_dir, 'rb').read()).hexdigest()
            if 'md5Checksum' in drive_file.keys():
                # print(1, file['md5Checksum'])
                drive_md5 = drive_file['md5Checksum']
                # print(2, os_file_md5)
            else:
                # print('No hash')
                drive_md5 = None
                # print(drive_md5 != os_file_md5)

            if (file_time > drive_time) or (drive_md5 != os_file_md5):
                file_id = [f['id'] for f in items
                           if f['name'] == drive_file['name']][0]
                file_mime = [f['mimeType'] for f in items
                             if f['name'] == drive_file['name']][0]

                # File's new content.
                # file_mime = mimetypes.MimeTypes().guess_type(file_dir)[0]
                file_metadata = {'name': drive_file['name'],
                                 'parents': [parents_id[last_dir]]}
                # media_body = MediaFileUpload(file_dir, mimetype=filemime)
                media_body = MediaFileUpload(file_dir, mimetype=file_mime)
                # print('I am HERE, ', )
                service.files().update(fileId=file_id,
                                       media_body=media_body,
                                       fields='id').execute()

        # Remove old files from Drive
        for drive_file in remove_files:

            file_id = [f['id'] for f in items
                       if f['name'] == drive_file['name']][0]
            service.files().delete(fileId=file_id).execute()

        # Upload new files on Drive
        for os_file in upload_files:

            file_dir = os.path.join(variable, os_file)

            # File's new content.
            filemime = mimetypes.MimeTypes().guess_type(file_dir)[0]
            file_metadata = {'name': os_file,
                             'parents': [parents_id[last_dir]]}
            media_body = MediaFileUpload(file_dir, mimetype=filemime)

            service.files().create(body=file_metadata,
                                   media_body=media_body,
                                   fields='id').execute()

    remove_folders = sorted(remove_folders, key=by_lines, reverse=True)

    # Delete old folders from Drive
    for folder_dir in remove_folders:
        var = (os.path.sep).join(full_path.split(
            os.path.sep)[0:-1]) + os.path.sep
        variable = var + folder_dir
        last_dir = folder_dir.split('/')[-1]
        folder_id = parents_id[last_dir]
        service.files().delete(fileId=folder_id).execute()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: In your situation, can I ask you about the necessity that you are using `oauth2client` instead of `google.auth`? If you try to use `google.auth`, will the result be changed? About the script of authorization, you can see it at [the official document](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python).

Comment: Thank you. I actually have ever tried the code in the official document you mentioned. I'm trying now and shows perfectly the same phenomenon, no response.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. In your case, what browser are you using? In my environment, I can confirm that when I use Chrome, the script works and the authorization code can be retrieved with `google.auth`.

Comment: Safari on Mac. I changed the default web browser to Chrome and yes, the redirection worked fine! Thank you for your great advice. However, on iOS (iphone), the situation is not so simple. Safari does not respond (just like on Mac) and changing the default web browser to Chrome, authentication code is not delivered to the App and shows error. (And sometimes successful..) Anyway, it sounds like it is related to the web browser.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I also think that your issue might be due to the dependence on the browser.

Comment: Yes. And I cannot do anything about the browser behavior and seems like this kind of "Programmatic extraction" for OAuth2 is deprecated (https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/native-app), so probably I better change the approach. Anyway, thank you for useful advice!

Comment: Thank you for replying. I think that this issue might be resolved in the future update. But as the current sitaution, about the information, can you post it as an answer? By this, I think that it will be useful for other users who have the same issue.

Comment: Sure, will do it! It is definitely an answer.

Comment: I'm still not well understanding the stack overflow rule, but if you write an "answer" and I mark it as an "accept", you can get score, correct?

Comment: I posted it as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If you have the additional information, feel free to tell me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the current stage, it seems that the issue depends on the browser. For example,

- When Chrome is used, no issue occurs.
- When Safari is used, such issue occurs.

  - From [Taka's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65622850/google-oauth2-authentication-issue-no-web-browser-response-after-user-consent?noredirect=1#comment116026914_65622850), it seems "sometimes successful".

Although I think that this issue might be resolved in the future update, as the current answer, it is considered that the issue depends on the browser.